# I'm getting extra space in front of the third row of buttons

Tags: html, css, button, whitespace, space

I need to get another button line(third row) same as the second row of buttons in the screen. So that I copy paste the code of the second row of buttons .But I'm getting extra space in front of the third row of buttons. Need to remove that extra space(mentioned that extra space with blue arrow in the output picture which i have attached). please help. thank you

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrpRL.png)

```
 <!--start: Content -->
<div id="content" class="span10">

<!--breadcrum-->
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('dashoard')?>">Home</a> 
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    </ul>

<!--read reports-->
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span3 statbox yellow" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span3" style="height:150px;">
            <div class="boxchart">5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4,8,2,3,3,2</div>
            <div class="number"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></div>
            <div class="title">Orders</div>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/order');?>">Read Full Report</a>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="span3 statbox green" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span3" style="height:150px;">
            <div class="boxchart">5,6,7,2,0,-4,-2,4,8,2,3,3,2</div>
            <div class="number"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></div>
            <div class="title">Income</div>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/order');?>">Read Full Report</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 statbox blue" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span3" style="height:150px;">
            <div class="boxchart">5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4,8,2,3,3,2</div>
            <div class="number"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></div>
            <div class="title">Status</div>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('Job/view_jobs');?>">Read Full Report</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 statbox red" onTablet="span6" onDesktop="span3" style="height:150px;">
            <div class="boxchart">7,2,2,2,1,-4,-2,4,8,,0,3,3,5</div>
            <div class="number"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></div>
            <div class="title">Products</div>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/product')?>">Read Full Report</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

<!--buttons-->
    <div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/product')?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox blueDark">
                <div class="header">Manage Product</div>
                    <i class="icon-barcode" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/order');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox red">
                <div class="header">Manage Order</div>
                    <i class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="#">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox pink">
                <div class="header">Customer Feedback</div><br>
                    <i class="icon-group" style="font-size:80px;"></i>  
                    <i class="icon-comments-alt" style="font-size:80px;"></i>
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/category')?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox greenLight">
                <div class="header">Manage Category</div><br>
                    <i class="icon-qrcode" style="font-size:100px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('Job');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox purple">
                <div class="header">Assign Delivery</div>
                    <i class="icon-truck" style="font-size:110px;"></i> 
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('theme/option');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox greenDark">
                <div class="header">Manage Theme</div>
                    <i class="icon-cogs" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <!--third row-->
    <div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/product')?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox blueDark">
                <div class="header">Manage Product</div>
                    <i class="icon-barcode" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/order');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox red">
                <div class="header">Manage Order</div>
                    <i class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="#">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox pink">
                <div class="header">Customer Feedback</div><br>
                    <i class="icon-group" style="font-size:80px;"></i>  
                    <i class="icon-comments-alt" style="font-size:80px;"></i>
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('manage/category')?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox greenLight">
                <div class="header">Manage Category</div><br>
                    <i class="icon-qrcode" style="font-size:100px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('Job');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox purple">
                <div class="header">Assign Delivery</div>
                    <i class="icon-truck" style="font-size:110px;"></i> 
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('theme/option');?>">
            <div class="circleStatsItemBox greenDark">
                <div class="header">Manage Theme</div>
                    <i class="icon-cogs" style="font-size:110px;"></i>    
                <div class="footer"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
<!-- end: Content-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The button row seems to be wrapped in `<div class="row-fluid hideInIE8 circleStats">` which could cause the row to have a slightly bigger margin.